# Shortest time to cook burgers

Tags: mathematics, optimization, strategy

Attribution: I remember seeing this type of question some time ago but don't remember from where. So I have redesigned the question. Hope that is OK.

You have 5 burger patties to grill. Each side takes 1 minute total to cook. Both sides need full grilling. Your grill can only handle 3 patties at a time. You are in a rush. What is the least amount of time you can fully cook those patties?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Frying Three Steaks](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/31929/5373)

Comment: @Randal'Thor that problem seems more complicated as you also need to butter and other constraints.

Comment: Related: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/64558/5-tires-with-maximum-distance, and the classic puzzle of having 6 tires on a four-wheeled vehicle (4 installed, 2 spares), each with 1000km lifetime, trying to reach 1500km distance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If we make the (rather dubious) assumption that

> all that matters is that each side of each patty should end up having been on the grill for at least 1 minute (so that cooking for 1 minute is equivalent to cooking for 30 seconds, waiting 1 minute, then cooking for another 30 seconds)

then

> we can do the job in the theoretical minimum of 10/3 minutes = 3 minutes 20 seconds, as follows. The table has 10 burger-sides along the top, and 10 20-second periods along the left. "##" indicates cooking. "//" indicates the last 20-second period a given burger-side needs.
>
> ```
>   1a 1b 2a 2b 3a 3b 4a 4b 5a 5b
> 0 ##    ##    ##
> 1 ##    ##    ##
> 2 //    //    //
> 3    ##    ##    ##
> 4    ##             ##    ##
> 5    //             ##    ##
> 6          ##       //    //
> 7          //          ##    ##
> 8                ##    ##    ##
> 9                //    //    //
> ```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the minimum time for a pattie to cook on one side is 1 minute, the answer is

> 4 minutes

Observe that

> With 5 patties there are 10 sides that need to be cooked. Since our grill can only cook 3 patties per minute, we will need at least $\lceil{10/3}\rceil=4$ minutes.

Here is how this lower bound can be reached

> Denote patties as A, B, C, D and E. Use numbers to denote which side we are cooking. We can now cook like so:
>  1. A1 B1 C1
>  2. D1 E1 A2
>  3. B2 C2 D2
>  4. E2

There are many other solutions too.

Comment: This puzzle brought back many great memories as this was the first problem I wrote for TopCoder back in 2003. See the general solution to this problem under FryingHamburgers here: https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/SRM%20159

Comment: Why the need for ceiling function here?

Comment: Well I was assuming that the minimum time you can have the patties on one side is 1 minute.

Comment: Ah, ok. I hadn't considered that case since this is a classic problem for me, where a few things needs to be allocated to a few slots, but one thing can only be used at one slot at a time (one side of steak grilled at a time in this case), and I assume we can do partially. The classic problem is trying to get a car (4 wheels) with 1 spare, where each tire has a lifetime of 1000km, and asking how to reach 1250km.